# Any way to customize the blank option ng-options creates for a dropdown?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

So believe it or not, I want and am happy with the creation of a blank option on the dropdown, but I want to do a bit more.

I would like to tell angular to use a string of my choosing when it creates it's blank option.  For example, I would like it to say "-select-" rather than an empty string in that blank option it creates.  The thing is that I like the way the blank option isn't available once a choice is made.  While it isn't too big a deal to add an object to the array I bind to that looks like I want, that starts requiring additional code for the dropdown to mimic the behavior ng-options gives us already.  It isn't such a big deal, but it gets arduous and frustrating when it has to be done for a lot of dropdowns.

Does anyone know if there is a way to tell ng-options what to display when there is no match to the ng-model value?  It would be nice if there is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have a default option in select box - Angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js)

Answer (score 1):

I found what works well enough for my needs.

```
<select ng-options="lang.Name for lang in Languages"
        required>
    <option value="">Select Language</option>
 </select>
```

Ng-options will use the value in the select if there is no match to an item in Languages.  The only thing that doesn't behave the same (which many people prefer) is that the blank option always stays present.  However the angular required validation handles it well without any additional work.  So that works for my purposes.