# Angular - Need to add multiple place-holders to a select drop-down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, drop-down-menu

Although this may not be the best UI implementation, I have a drop-down list with several elements that must be grouped using multiple placeholders (e.g. ----- group 1 -----).  I'd like to make the place-holders un-selectable.

I found a solution for a single placeholder here: 
[How do I add an unselectable and customizable placeholder to a select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247608/angularjs-how-do-i-add-an-unselectable-and-customizable-placeholder-to-a-select)

but it doesn't seem to be extendable to multiple place-holders.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Not angular specific, but can you use select option groups?

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp and their demo at
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup

Comment: I learn something new everyday (optgroup).  I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) has support for automatically adding <optgroup> tags. Check out the `group by` syntax.