# using ng-option in updating angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I am creating a web app in which I use c# and angularjs. In my updated syntax of the dropdownlist I used ng-option(`as recommended by some people`).

This is my dropdownlist:

```
<select ng-option="comnamelistfun as comnamelistfun.comname for comname in comnamelistfun track by comnamelistfun.comname" ng-model="ucomname"></select>
```

This is my js for calling the data:

```
 //comnamebyid
            $http.get('/csuv5.asmx/getcompanyname', {
                params: {
                    log: log,
                    pm: pm,
                    id: $scope.updateparam.Id
                }
            })

            .then(function (response) {
                {
                    $scope.comnamelistfun = response.data.cdetails;
                    $scope.ucomname = $scope.comnamelistfun[0];
                    console.log($scope.ucomname);
                }
            });
```

I know there is something wrong with my code, can anybody help me out?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: i am not getting the data in my dropdownlist

Comment: can u show the data in $scope.comnamelistfun ?

Comment: In the console?

Comment: `Object {comname: "QED Productions Pvt Ltd"}
$$hashKey
:
"object:150"
comname
:
"QED Productions Pvt Ltd"
__proto__
:
Object`

Comment: yeh...I could have see the structure of you data which returned by server call?

Comment: would be helpful, if you create fiddle without your http call with static data..

Comment: i have a web service which is providing the data

Comment: can u create a fiddle with the static data(like server response)???

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348886/angularjs-ng-options-not-binding-after-ajax-call

Comment: @Manikandan i tried to create a fiddle but unable to succeed

Comment: @IbrahimShaikh - Your data looks like it is in json format. Parse it as I have explained in my answer

Answer (score 0):

you are not iterating on comnamelistfun correctly Try This -

```
<select ng-option="c as c.comname for c in comnamelistfun track by c.comname" ng-model="ucomname"></select>
```

Comment: i will make it more easier

Comment: ooh... need revisit issue again

Comment: my data is dynamic it is working with static data but not with dynamic data

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle for this. Hope this will help you. Since i haven't any idea about your data structure i put some dummy data as per my concern.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <span>Default Otions:</span>
        <select ng-model="mail_notification" ng-options="c as c.value for c in mail_notifications"></select>
        <br />

        <br />                
    </div>
</div>
```

js file

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.mail_notifications = [
            {
                "value": "For any event on all my projects"
            },
            {
                "value": "For any event on the selected projects only..."
            },
            {
                "value": "Only for things I watch or I'm involved in"
            },
            {
                "value": "Only for things I am assigned to"
            },
            {
                "value": "Only for things I am the owner of"
            },
            {
                "value": "No events"
            }
        ];
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mvs2809/bjs3g/110/

Comment: `{"cdetails":[{"comname":"QED Productions Pvt Ltd"},{"comname":"A-1 Heights \u0026 Hospitality Private Limited"},{"comname":"Absolute Hospitality Services"},{"comname":"Air India Ltd"},{"comname":"Amara Raja Industrial Service Pvt. Ltd"},{"comname":"ANS International"},{"comname":"Atmosphere Hotels and Resorts"},{"comname":"Azure Hospitality Pvt Ltd"},{"comname":"Bajaj Finance Limited"},{"comname":"Bauer India Ltd"},{"comname":"Cafe Zoe"},{"comname":"Care Facility Management Services"},{"comname":"Zodiac Clothing Co Ltd"}]}`


this is how i am getting the data

Comment: @IbrahimShaikh - have you realised whats the issue??? you are not iterating over element you are in your trying to add option from your list. check my answer, i have edited the same

Comment: @Manikandan it is working with static data but not with dynamic data

Comment: Ok. Then it should be the problem of the scope variable. can you replaces your js code with this and console output?   
            .success(function (response) {
                {
                    console.log(response);
                }
instead of using 'then' in your code replace with success?

Comment: the data above is that the result of  console.log($scope.ucomname); ?

Comment: Then it is because of the scope variable in which the response you are setting. So make sure that the data in $scope.comnamelistfun is like [{"comname":"QED Productions Pvt Ltd"},etc.... }]

Answer (score 0):

Check this example, it is showing the `comname` property and sets the '*object* ' containing `comname` into the property specified in the `ng-model` directive.

```js
angular
    .module('demo', [])
    .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = {
        "cdetails": [{
            "comname": "QED Productions Pvt Ltd"
        }, {
            "comname": "A-1 Heights \u0026 Hospitality Private Limited"
        }, {
            "comname": "Absolute Hospitality Services"
        }, {
            "comname": "Air India Ltd"
        }, {
            "comname": "Amara Raja Industrial Service Pvt. Ltd"
        }, {
            "comname": "ANS International"
        }, {
            "comname": "Atmosphere Hotels and Resorts"
        }, {
            "comname": "Azure Hospitality Pvt Ltd"
        }, {
            "comname": "Bajaj Finance Limited"
        }, {
            "comname": "Bauer India Ltd"
        }, {
            "comname": "Cafe Zoe"
        }, {
            "comname": "Care Facility Management Services"
        }, {
            "comname": "Zodiac Clothing Co Ltd"
        }]
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <select ng-model="ctrl.selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.comname for item in ctrl.data.cdetails">
      <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to show `comname` property to the user as well as set the `comname` property value into the variable bound in the `ng-model` directive (i.e. for retrieval purposes), then you don't need to use the `track by` clause

```js
angular
    .module('demo', [])
    .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.selectedItem = "Air India Ltd";
    vm.data = {
        "cdetails": [{
            "comname": "QED Productions Pvt Ltd"
        }, {
            "comname": "A-1 Heights \u0026 Hospitality Private Limited"
        }, {
            "comname": "Absolute Hospitality Services"
        }, {
            "comname": "Air India Ltd"
        }, {
            "comname": "Amara Raja Industrial Service Pvt. Ltd"
        }, {
            "comname": "ANS International"
        }, {
            "comname": "Atmosphere Hotels and Resorts"
        }, {
            "comname": "Azure Hospitality Pvt Ltd"
        }, {
            "comname": "Bajaj Finance Limited"
        }, {
            "comname": "Bauer India Ltd"
        }, {
            "comname": "Cafe Zoe"
        }, {
            "comname": "Care Facility Management Services"
        }, {
            "comname": "Zodiac Clothing Co Ltd"
        }]
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <select ng-model="ctrl.selectedItem" ng-options="item.comname as item.comname for item in ctrl.data.cdetails">
      <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data that you are getting is JSON. You need to parse it before you use it. try this:

```
 $scope.comnamelistfun = JSON.parse(response.data.cdetails);
```