# Select and display one chart using dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have two charts that I want to display using a dropdown menu. but I tried the both options (using JQuery / AngularJS), but I have difficulties to do it working.

I have two charts

```
<div  ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <nvd3-discrete-bar-chart
            data="exampleData"
            id="exampleId"
            width="800"
            height="400"
            tooltips="true"
            showXAxis="true"
            showYAxis="true">
        <svg></svg>
    </nvd3-discrete-bar-chart>

    <nvd3-discrete-bar-chart
            data="exampleData2"
            id="exampleId2"
            width="800"
            height="400"
            tooltips="true"
            showXAxis="true"
            showYAxis="true">
        <svg></svg>
    </nvd3-discrete-bar-chart>    
</div>
```

I want to use dropdown menu to change the charts

```
<select id="leave" onchange="leaveChange()">
  <option value="1">Second</option>
  <option value="2">First</option>

</select>
```

The function to select the chart is:

```
function leaveChange() {
    if (document.getElementById("leave").value != "1"){
 document.getElementById("test").data="exampleData2";
    }     
    else{
        document.getElementById("test").data="exampleData";
    }        
}
```

Using Jquery: 
http://jsfiddle.net/K3Lwj/3/

Comment: The main problem aside, your fiddle has a bunch of errors. Why does your graph have two IDs? Remove one and keep the other. Instead of using onchange for select tags, use onclick. Instead of value, you'll need to use selectedIndex.

Comment: Based on your comments, how can select the chart in this case (or how can I inject data source ?) :; check updates http://jsfiddle.net/K3Lwj/4/

Comment: or should I start thinking of using Angular JS dropdown menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thought to use an Angular `ng-options` select menu is I believe a good one, because the way you are interspersing plain javascript with Angular does not seem like a particularly "Angular" way of going about the problem. For instance, in the spot where you are using `onclick`, I would recommend going with Angular's `ng-change` and putting the `select` inside the controller.

Here is an example, building largely on your original, and using a bit more of an Angular approach to tackle the issue:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/9GSNs/

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app='nvd3TestApp'>
    <div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
        <select ng-init="selectedChart.chart = chartOptions[0]; updateChart()" ng-model="selectedChart.chart" ng-change="updateChart()" ng-options="c.name for c in chartOptions track by c.id"></select>
        <nvd3-discrete-bar-chart data="exampleData" id="exampleId" width="800" height="400" tooltips="true" showXAxis="true" showYAxis="true">
            <svg></svg>
        </nvd3-discrete-bar-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

```
angular.module("nvd3TestApp", ['nvd3ChartDirectives']);

function ExampleCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.chartOptions = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Option 1"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Option 2"
    }];

    var d1 = [{
        key: "Cumulative Return",
        values: [
            ["A", -29.765957771107],
            ["B", 0],
            ["C", 32.807804682612],
            ["D", 196.45946739256],
            ["E", 0.19434030906893],
            ["F", -98.079782601442],
            ["G", -13.925743130903],
            ["H", -5.1387322875705]
        ]
    }];

    var d2 = [{
        key: "Cumulative Return",
        values: [
            ["A", -29.765957771107],
            ["B", 0],
            ["C", 32.807804682612],
            ["D", 196.45946739256],
            ["E", 0.19434030906893],
            ["F", -98.079782601442],
            ["G", -13.925743130903],
            ["H", -5.1387322875705]
        ]
    }, {
        key: "Cumulative Return2",
        values: [
            ["A", 10.765957771107],
            ["B", 0],
            ["C", -32.807804682612],
            ["D", 96.45946739256],
            ["E", 0.19434030906893],
            ["F", -38.079782601442],
            ["G", -43.925743130903],
            ["H", -3.1387322875705]
        ]
    }];

    $scope.updateChart = function () {
        if ($scope.selectedChart.chart === undefined || $scope.selectedChart.chart.id === 1) {
            $scope.exampleData = d1;
        }
        if ($scope.selectedChart.chart !== undefined && $scope.selectedChart.chart.id === 2) {
            $scope.exampleData = d2;
        }
    };

    $scope.$on('tooltipShow.directive', function (event) {
        //console.log('scope.tooltipShow', event);
    });

    $scope.$on('tooltipHide.directive', function (event) {
        //console.log('scope.tooltipHide', event);
    });

}
```

It is worth having a read of Scott Allen's post about using ngOptions.
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/19/using-ngoptions-in-angularjs.aspx

Regarding intializing select value, see this stackoverflow post:
[How to have a default option in Angular.js select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js)