# How can I make a <select> default to a value when the page opens?

Tags: angularjs

I created a web page with a select like this:

```
<select ng-model="access.method">
    <option>DELETE</option>
    <option>GET</option>
    <option>POST</option>
    <option>PUT</option>
</select>
```

and then a retrieve:

```
$http({
    method: access.method,
    url: access.url
})
```

How can I make it so that when the web page opens that it defaults to the GET option ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have a default option in select box - Angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select ng-init="access.method='POST'" ng-model="access.method">
    <option>DELETE</option>
    <option>GET</option>
    <option>POST</option>
    <option>PUT</option>
</select>
```