# Select the blank option of select box programmatically in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a select box with a blank option and some other options. The options are not generated with ngOptions directive, because they are generated on server side (with Symfony forms).

In some cases I want to unselect the selected value of the select box. So that the blank option is selected. But I cannot get this to work. The select box does not get updated.

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4s2YE/3/) to show the problem.

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="form">
        <select ng-model="foo.hero" name="foo[hero]" my-directive="">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">Batman</option>
            <option value="2">Superman</option>
            <option value="3">Spiderman</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <p>Selected: {{ foo.hero }}</p>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.foo = {hero: '2'};
}

myApp.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        require: ['ngModel', '?form'],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctlrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                var modelController = ctlrs[0];
                modelController.$setViewValue('');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have a default option in select box - Angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js)

Comment: Not really. My problem is, that I have to change the selected value in a directive.

Comment: OK, `ng-init` doesn't fit because the value is changing at some point later? you need to do this at some point `later? In that case I'd probably write an `ng-timeout` that mirrors `ng-init` functionality but wraps it in `$timeout`... Effectively what @Delta does below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modelController.$render() after you call $setViewValue. This will update the DOM element(s).

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        require: ['ngModel', '?form'],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctlrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                var modelController = ctlrs[0];
                modelController.$setViewValue('');
                modelController.$render();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4s2YE/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
        $timeout(function() {
            scope.foo.hero = '';
        });
```

since the model of your select is foo.hero whenever you change it then the select will change the selected.

Comment: But that does not make the form dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to muck around with `modelController`? Can't you just update the model to the default value?

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            model: '=?ngModel'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctlrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.model = '';
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4s2YE/5/).

Comment: But that does not make the form dirty.

Comment: True, but your question didn't state that was a requirement!