# AngularJS ngOptions select default option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have the following `select` element that is dynamically populated using angular's ngOptions directive.

```
<select ng-options="group.parameterGroupId as group.name for group in parameterGroups" 
        ng-change="getParameterGroup(group.parameterGroupId)" 
        ng-model="group.parameterGroupId">
    <option value="">== Choose Group ==</option>
</select>
```

How can I programatically select the default `== Choose Group ==` option later on, after another value in the dropdown has been selected?

I have tried setting `$scope.group.parameterGroupId` to `null` and to `""` in my controller, neither of which worked as expected. In both cases, the option that was currently selected stays selected.

Using AngularJS v1.4.3.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411820/select-the-blank-option-of-select-box-programmatically-in-angularjs-directive?

Comment: No, that question doesn't deal with ngOptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that my `<select>` was included in my page using the ngInclude directive. I discovered that the ngInclude directive actually creates a child scope for the template being included. So, to be able to set the selected group, I needed to make the `ng-model` of my select accessible from its parent scope.

I ended up incorporating @Italo Ayres's solution as well, to access the default value of my select. Here is my corrected markup, which uses `$parent` to access the parent scope of my template that my `<select>` is contained in.

```
<select ng-options="group.parameterGroupId as group.name for group in parameterGroups" 
        ng-change="getParameterGroup(group.parameterGroupId)" 
        ng-model="$parent.group.parameterGroupId">
    <option value="" ng-model="$parent.defaultGroup">== Choose Group ==</option>
</select>
```

Then in my controller, I set the selected group to the default like this.

```
$scope.group {
    parameterGroupId: $scope.defaultGroup
};
```

Note that I don't use `$scope.group.parameterGroupId = $scope.defaultGroup` because `$scope.group` may not be defined when this statement is reached.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could atribute some model to your defult option. Take a look:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.options = [
        { desc: 'op1' },
        { desc: 'op2' },
        { desc: 'op3' }
    ]
    $scope.reset = function(){
     $scope.selected = $scope.default;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-options="op as op.desc for op in options" ng-model="selected">
    <option value="" ng-model="default">== Choose Group ==</option>
  </select>
    {{selected}}
    
    <br />
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset!</button>
</div>
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, this helped, but the heart of the problem was that my select was included in the page using an ngInclude, which creates a child scope for the template.

Comment: But did you figured it out in the end? Or are you still trying? @AndrewMairose

Comment: I figured it out. I posted my solution in another answer.