# Angularjs select with no selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, selectedindex, angularjs-ng-options

This seems like a really simple thing I'm looking for and the fact that I can't find anything on SO or anywhere else makes me think I must be missing something really obvious, but so far I'm stumped.  My question is; is there any way, when using a select box set up with ng-options, to set the list to no selection (i.e. selectedIndex = -1)?  I have a select box set up as a non-dropdown and I want to be able to display the list with nothing selected.

I'm adding the code I use below, but I believe it's pretty standard stuff.  The curSearchResults array is populated from the server.  I'm not including that here since it is working fine.  I've tried setting selSearchRslt to null and back to a new searchRslt() after fetching the list, but both leave a blank option at the top of the list.  I'm used to it being really simple to set a select box to no selection as desired...

at the controller:

```
function searchRslt() {
    this.RsltId = '';
    this.RsltName = '';
}
$scope.curSearchRslts = [];
$scope.selSearchRslt = new searchRslt();
```

in the markup:

```
<select class="listPanel" 
   ng-model="selSearchRslt" 
   ng-options="rslt as rslt.RsltName for rslt in curSearchRslts" 
   ng-change="loadSearchRslt()"
   size="40" style="height: 300px; width: 480px">
</select>
```

This is in response to the comments below:

I read the questions you refer to and I did see the stuff in the doc about adding the option to the markup, but this doesn't give the same result as setting the selected index to -1. Instead it adds an unused option to my list. Particularly when the list isn't displayed as a dropdown, I find this solution to be very clunky in terms of the UI. I don't want that extra option. I want just the options I'm actually going to use, but with none selected. If the answer is I can't do that, fine, but adding an unused option is certainly not the same thing as setting the selectedIndex to -1.

Further, I'm not looking for a way to set a default option, I'm looking for a way to have no option selected.  I don't get how this is viewed as the same thing.  I find it very easy to set a default selection.  I never would've posted a question about that.  I haven't found anything that offers a way to have NO selection.  If I'm missing something here and have gone completely brain dead, please accept my apologies, but I don't see how the question referred to in any way answers this question.

Comment: Did you look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js and there are numerous others. All you need to do is to add an option in the select

Comment: The question is clearly answered in the Angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select. See setting <option value = ""> </option> within your <select>. This is mentioned in the HTML example at the bottom of the doc.

Comment: It seems like my question sort of got kicked to the curb since it was marked as a duplicate and that's a shame because no one has responded to my edit stating why I think this is wrong.  I've come to the conclusion you can't set a ng-options bound select list to no selection and I think it's a miss in Angularjs (which I otherwise love).  As far as I'm concerned saying that adding a blank (or -- Please Select --) option is a solution is a red herring that doesn't really address the issue.  Maybe an ng-noSelection directive or something like that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to create an empty option:

```
<select class="listPanel" 
   ng-model="selSearchRslt" 
   ng-options="rslt as rslt.RsltName for rslt in curSearchRslts" 
   ng-change="loadSearchRslt()"
   size="40" style="height: 300px; width: 480px">
  <option value="">-- Please Select --<option>
</select>
```