# Specifying Angular ngModel Value with ng-repeated options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I've got a select dropdown, whose options are being ng-repeated out of an object called `$scope.bars`.

However, my ng-model, which is set to a sub-value of `$scope.bars`, is not correctly choosing an option. Instead, the select box is blank by default, indicating an 'undefined' value.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="programApp" ng-controller="programController">
  <label>Level: 
    <select ng-model="advancedFilters">
      <option ng-repeat="item in bars" value="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

And here's my Angular code:

```
angular.module('programApp', [
    'programApp.controllers',
]);
angular.module('programApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('programController', ['$scope',  
    function($scope){

      $scope.advancedFilters = 1;

      $scope.bars = [
        {'name':'First',
          'id':1},
        {'name':'Second',
          'id':2},
        {'name':'Third',
          'id':3},
        {'name':'Fourth',
          'id':4},
        {'name':'Fifth',
          'id':5}];
    }]);
```

Because `$scope.advancedFilters` is equal to 1, the dropdown should display the 'First' option, because the first dropdown option has an id value of 1. Instead, the dropdown is blank, indicating a problem with ng-model.

How do I fix this?

**See a Codepen here: http://codepen.io/trueScript/pen/PqbVyv**

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to run into these kind of issues if you use ng-repeat for select. Try use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead. i.e

```
 <select ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in bars" 
         ng-model="advancedFilters">
</select>
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/pramodsankarl/pen/pJNGBE)**

`item.id       as item.name   for item in bars` represents

`selectedValue as displayName for item in list`

Even if your ng-model is not defined or not one of the items in the list, you could set up a default option as well with this by doing:

```
<select ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in bars" 
         ng-model="advancedFilters">
   <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
</select>
```

Otherwise you need to provide value as interpolated (`value="{{item.id}}"`) when using ng-repeat, i.e

```
<option ng-repeat="item in bars" 
        value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/pramodsankarl/pen/vOybwb)**