# How to add default --select-- field in using ng-options in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

I need --select-- field as a default value with ng-options

```
 <select ng-model="editedField.operator" ng-options="operator as operator for operator in opConditions"></select>
```

Comment: RTFM ~ [*"Optionally, a single hard-coded `<option>` element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the `<select>` element. This element will then represent the null or "not selected" option."*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't write code for you, especially without showing some effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
 <select ng-model="editedField.operator" ng-options="operator as operator for 
 operator in opConditions">
<option value>Select</option>
</select>
```