# select dropdown not binding initially to AngularJS model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

Ok so my issue is that I have a simple select dropdown, and am using ng-repeat to populate the dropdown, like below:

```
<select ng-model="tstCtrl.model.value" required>
  <option ng-repeat="option in tstCtrl.myOptions" value="{{option.a}}">{{option.b}}</option>
</select>
```

After selecting an option, the binding to *model.value* works fine, but until then it doesn't seem to bind the selected dropdown option to the value *model.value* is initially set to.

This is demonstrated below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    angular.module('Test', []).controller('TestController', function(){
      
      this.model = {
        value:3
      };
      
      this.myOptions = [
        {a:1, b:"one"},
        {a:2, b:"two"},
        {a:3, b:"three"},
        {a:4, b:"four"},
        {a:5, b:"five"}];
    });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="Test" ng-controller="TestController as tstCtrl">

    {{tstCtrl.model.value}}

    <select ng-model="tstCtrl.model.value" required>
      <option ng-repeat="option in tstCtrl.myOptions" value="{{option.a}}">{{option.b}}</option>
    </select>

  </body>



</html>
```

I think the above snippet makes it really clear, but am happy to answer any questions.

How do I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you use ng-repeat instead of [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)?

Comment: Only because I prefer it syntactically, will it work with ng-options do you think?

Comment: I do think so, the example in the documentation sets a default. If you want to stick to your approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/khjdgk82/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely must use `ng-repeat`, you could do it like this:

```
    <select ng-model="tstCtrl.model.value">
      <option ng-repeat="option in tstCtrl.myOptions" value="{{option.a}}" 
              ng-selected="tstCtrl.model.value==option.a">
                   {{option.b}}
       </option>
    </select>
```

but I agree with the others who advised to use `ng-options` instead.

Comment: I went with this option, mainly because there may be non-Angular developers looking at this code from time to time, and this is much easier to read. I feel that ng-options will just confuse people

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use the `ng-options` syntax instead of an `ng-repeat` inside your select. If you want to display property `b` but bind to property `a` you can use the following syntax:

```
<select ng-model="model.value" ng-options="option.a as option.b for option in myOptions" required>      
</select>
```

Here's your modified working snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    angular.module('Test', []).controller('TestController', function($scope){
      
      $scope.model = {
        value:3
      };
      
      $scope.myOptions = [
        {a:1, b:"one"},
        {a:2, b:"two"},
        {a:3, b:"three"},
        {a:4, b:"four"},
        {a:5, b:"five"}];
    });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="Test" ng-controller="TestController">

    {{model.value}}

    <select ng-model="model.value" ng-options="option.a as option.b for option in myOptions"  required>      
    </select>

  </body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Theres a known issue with going from AngularJS 1.3.x to 1.4, specifically with ng-model and select dropdowns. In short, the Angular documentation was updated and they gave the more proper way to fix this issue:

```
app.directive('convertToNumber', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {                
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {                    
                return parseInt(val, 10);
            });
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (val) {                    
                return '' + val;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And in your select dropdown, add the directive:

```
<select ng-model="tstCtrl.model.value" convert-to-number required>
  <option ng-repeat="option in tstCtrl.myOptions" value="{{option.a}}">{{option.b}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is the reference URL where the above solution originated from:

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/May/21/Angular-Select-List-Value-not-binding-with-Static-Values

Answer (score 0):

Just need ng-options instead of ng-repeat like this:

```
ng-options="option.a as option.b for option in myOptions"
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?