# Adding angular directives to simple_form in rails breaks selected option for collection input

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Not sure if there's a workaround for this, I'm doing something wrong, or this is a collision between simple form or angular, but:

```
.field
  = f.input :role, collection: roles.map(&:name), selected: user.role.try(:name), include_blank: 'Select', required: true, input_html: { "ng-model" => "role" }
```

renders (which looks correct):

```
   <select ng-model="role" class="select required" name="user[role]" id="user_role">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="system">system</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="fcm">fcm</option>
      <option value="regulatory">regulatory</option>
      <option value="operations">operations</option>
      <option value="help_desk">help_desk</option>
     </select>
```

But the selected value is the `include_blank` value of 'Select'. And yes, `role` is set on the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's doing this is because of the way angular models work and it requires an understanding of this. Essentially the ruby generates the `select` correctly choosing the `selected` option of the select box too.

However, once the angular is loaded and sees `ng-model` on this `select` it sets the current selected option to the value of the model, in your case, `role`.

Thus if you want to have an angular model for this `select`, you need to set the initial value of that model.

Try the following:

```
.field
= f.input :role, collection: roles.map(&:name), include_blank: 'Select', required: true, input_html: { "ng-model" => "role", "ng-init" => "role = #{user.role.try(:name)}" }
```

Note that the `selected` option has been removed entirely since this will be controlled by the Angular model, which is initialized to that value using ruby string interpolation.

Answer (score -1):

I thought for a moment on this particular example and I am not quite sure what you expected to happen with the result.

Although, I assumed that you want to have  option with attribute `selected="selected"` selected as a default value, instead of `value=""`, which is only a blank field. If that I understood correctly and this is the point, that means there are several fields, which might be incorrect and We (the community) do not know how you completed them, but I think I dug up for the problem... ;)

**Angular directive** - At first, I do not know which version of angular you used in the example (I assume 1.X, because question have 6 months from this moment). The AngularJS `select` directive overrides the default behavior of `select` element and change it a bit.

I prepared a [simple example with Angular v1.0.1](http://jsfiddle.net/maciejsypien/uoges9qx/) for the tests and it looks behave correctly in few aspects. If you use `ng-model="role"` and set the role to `fcm` (String), like `$scope.role = 'fcm'`, the angular is obligate to set this value if it will find it.

I have also tested (AngularJS v1.0.1) what if the `role` is not set (undefined), then angular also point on empty string value like `value=""` and it not see into attribute `selected` and not set it as default. In the other side, the latest stable AngularJS v1.5.6 does support `selected` attribute [example with AngularJS v1.5.6](http://jsfiddle.net/maciejsypien/6880omdy/), so it might be the core of the problem.

Well, **the solution** for this is simple:

- upgrade AngularJS for the latest 1.X version or
- consider to use
  [`ngSelected`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)
  or [`ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)/[SO
  solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18195305/1977012) instead if the version AngularJS you used support that.

Comment: Looking for a solution with Rails + Angular, not a pure Angular method of creating a select option.  See my answer for the solution to this problem.