# ng-options comprehension_expression for simple array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Very simple question, maybe I just don't get it:

This is my array in my angular MainController:

```
vm.upcomingEventDates = [
    "2017-10-13",
    "2017-10-14",
    // [...]
];
```

And this is my select comprehension_expression:

```
<select ng-model="vm.booking.nextYearDate" ng-options="events as events for events in vm.upcomingEventDates">
```

But he keeps rendering it wrong (or not?):

```
<select ng-model="vm.booking.nextYearDate" ng-options="events as events for events in vm.upcomingEventDates" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
    <option value="?" selected="selected" label=""></option>
    <option value="0" label="2017-10-13">2017-10-13</option>
    <option value="1" label="2017-10-14">2017-10-14</option>
    <!-- [...] -->
</select>
```

How can I get rid of the first "wrong" value and get the date also in the value attribute?

Comment: Your model "vm.booking.nextYearDate" is not set to a value at rendering time. So angular adds an empty option. If you init the model with "2017-10-13" it may work like you want.

Comment: This post on SO could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js

Comment: Thanks you, solved it by adding a default value.