# ng-init is not setting my default category in my select within my Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-init

I have the exact same problem as mentioned here: [How to have a default option in Angular.js select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js)

However none of the answers fix my issue below, I'm trying to get the first category to show up inside of the select:

[image]

```
<p>Choose a tag category:</p>
<div class="select-style">
    <select ng-model="modal.addedTag" ng-init="modal.addedTag = modal.categories[0].name" ng-options="category.name for category in modal.categories">
        <!-- <option value="brand" selected>Brand</option> 
        <option value="client">Client</option>
        <option value="company-name">Company Name</option>
        <option value="government">Government</option>
        <option value="events">Events</option>
        <option value="industry">Industry</option>
        <option value="products">Products</option>
        <option value="news">News</option> -->
    </select>
</div>
```

---

Model in my Controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.categories = [
    { name: 'brand' },
    { name: 'client' },
    { name: 'competitor-name' },
    { name: 'company-name' },
    { name: 'government' },
    { name: 'events' },
    { name: 'industry' },
    { name: 'people' },
    { name: 'philanthropic' },
    { name: 'products' },
    { name: 'product-category' },
    { name: 'product-feature' },
    { name: 'place' },
    { name: 'problem' },
    { name: 'news' },
    { name: 'related-company-name' },
    { name: 'trend' }
];
```

Comment: Maybe because the options are commented out?

Comment: `ng-options` is suppose to act just like `ng-repeat` I actually just simply fixed this problem, by setting the default `ng-model`.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is the incorrect usage of ng-init, per the docs.  This easily could be (and should be) done in a controller.

Comment: you use `modal.categories[0].name` but you declared the `categories` variable on `vm`?

Comment: modal is was the directive `syntax as` keyword, I don't use $scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in controller.

if you use `ng-options="category.name for category in modal.categories"`  select tag then init  `vm.addedTag = vm.categories[0];` in controller. and also use `ng-options="category.name as category.name for category in modal.categories"` in select tag then init vm.addedTag model as this `vm.addedTag = vm.categories[0].name;`

```js
var myapp = angular.module('app', []);
myapp.controller('Main', function ($scope) {
 var vm = this;
vm.categories = [
    { name: 'brand' },
    { name: 'client' },
    { name: 'competitor-name' },
    { name: 'company-name' },
    { name: 'government' },
    { name: 'events' },
    { name: 'industry' },
    { name: 'people' },
    { name: 'philanthropic' },
    { name: 'products' },
    { name: 'product-category' },
    { name: 'product-feature' },
    { name: 'place' },
    { name: 'problem' },
    { name: 'news' },
    { name: 'related-company-name' },
    { name: 'trend' }
];
  vm.addedTag = vm.categories[0];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "app">
  <div ng-controller="Main as modal">

<div class="select-style">
    <select ng-model="modal.addedTag"  ng-options="category.name for category in modal.categories">
       
    </select>
</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

can try initialize `vm.addedTag` from `controller` instead of in `DOM`

```
vm.addedTag = vm.categories[0].name; // after your categories array
```

and in html use only `ng-model` no need to use `ng-init` and use `category.name as category.name`

```
<select ng-model="modal.addedTag" ng-options="category.name as category.name for category in modal.categories"></select>
```