# First change in ng-options display empty always blank

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

When I change the value from the select list, the first change display is always empty, and after the second change I have the display

I try with this code :

```
<select name="app_category_id" ng-model="campaign.app_category" ng-options="app_category.id as app_category.name group by app_category.app_category_pool[0].name for app_category in app_category_list | orderBy:['app_category_pool[0].name', 'name'] track by app_category.id" required>
</select>
```

My list :

```
$scope.app_category_list = [{
    "id": 31,
    "code": "RED",
    "name": "Red",
    "app_category_pool": [{
        "id": 1,
        "code": "CATEGORY_1",
        "name": "Category 1"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 32,
    "code": "BLUE",
    "name": "Blue",
    "app_category_pool": [{
        "id": 1,
        "code": "CATEGORY_1",
        "name": "Category 1",
    }]
}, {
    "id": 33,
    "code": "YELLOW",
    "name": "Yellow",
    "app_category_pool": [{
        "id": 2,
        "code": "CATEGORY_2",
        "name": "Category 2",
    }]
}]
```

After the first change (selection of another item from list) :

[image]

After the second change (selection of another item from list) :

[image]

I would like to use the id and group by category

When I load my page, my campaign.app_category own a value, after I select another item and I have a display blank:

```
$scope.campaign = {
    app_category: {
        "id": 31,
        "code": "RED",
        "name": "Red",
        "app_category_pool": [{
            "id": 1,
            "code": "CATEGORY_1",
            "name": "Category 1"
        }]
    }
}
```

I use angular 1.5.8

> SOLVED

http://plnkr.co/edit/6XYAQXG6hVh2J2PkfXIG?p=preview

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/5B7PcdZxaaqdZ7R5Nvjc?p=preview

Comment: Event with angular 1.5.8, this is working fine.. http://plnkr.co/edit/oTlUF94kprSMTjAv68gq?p=preview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js Hope this will solve your question.

Comment: I can reproduce my problem : http://plnkr.co/edit/6XYAQXG6hVh2J2PkfXIG?p=preview

Comment: What browser are you using? And the version no.
It works fine with the latest versions of firefox, chrome and edge

Comment: I use Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the HTML as follows:

```
ng-options="app_category as...
```

Remove `.id` and let the object only.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here it is working:

```
  <select name="app_category_id"
          ng-init="campaign.app_category = app_category_list[1]"
          ng-model="campaign.app_category" 
          ng-options="app_category as app_category.name group by app_category.app_category_pool[0].name for app_category in app_category_list | orderBy:['app_category_pool[0].name', 'name'] track by app_category.id"
          required>
  </select>
```

If you need to set another item as the default item, just change the ng-init number in the array. I selected the app_category_list[1] to show you that it works for Blue as default as well.

Comment: This is one way but why use ng-options and <options> together? Isn't it better to set a value to the model? @Setily

Comment: @EmptyCup: I edited my answer. You need to set a default option in some way. You can use the <option> example or ng-init for that.

Comment: my campaign.app_category is already set http://plnkr.co/edit/6XYAQXG6hVh2J2PkfXIG?p=preview

Comment: @JérémieChazelle: yes, your ng-model is set. You need to also set ng-init="campaign.app_category = '' "

Comment: @Setily Thx for your answer, but it's not the problem

Comment: @JérémieChazelle: How about now? :) I edited it again. Removed the id from ng-options and now it works correctly. Right? Here a working link: http://plnkr.co/edit/6XYAQXG6hVh2J2PkfXIG?p=preview