# How do I set the default option for select with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been working on trying to set the default pre-selected option for angularJS and for some reason I can't. Here is a [link to the relevant Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NgPGrklA3ng6bmnPjxmw?p=preview).

Here is the relevant code:

```
<select 
      ng-model="selectedOption" 
      ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in options">
    </select>
```

I've tried ng-init and a bunch of different ways; I can't figure how to make the top option the preselected one.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to have a default option in select box - Angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js)? You mention you've tried `ng-init` a bunch of ways -- have you tried it in the specific way it's used in that answer?

Comment: the answer in the proposed close as duplicate will work, but I wouldn't recommend using it, as this is not what `ng-init` was designed for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-select-box-angular-js) answer suggests using `ng-init`. I would go with assigning default option into `selectedOption` in controller or directive's `link` function:

```
$scope.selectedOption = options[0]
```

I don't see a need to use another directive for this simple task.

Comment: This worked. I am using an AJAX call to populate and thought it would be more complicated. On a related note, I am now having trouble setting the select within an ng-include template. It seems like copy-pasting the html causes the select statement to work fine, but just importing it via ng-include screws it up.

Comment: @iamsampsan, edit your question please with supporting code

Comment: @iamsampsan, what can I add to make my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to set one of the options pre-defined in `options`,
in your `ng-init` do something like `this $scope.selectedOption = <value>` where `<value>` is the value property of the object you want to be marked as selected by default. For example `1` if your first object in `options` would be, `{value: 1, name: "Option Number 1}`. See code below:

```
$scope.options = [{value:1, name: "Option 1"}, {value:2, name: "Options 2"}];

$scope.selectedOption = 1;
```

On the other hand, if you only want to show a predefined option indicating the user to select one option (and not one of the options in your `options`)...
This is a very simple (but effective way to achieve that). See code below:

```
<select
    ng-model="selectedOption"
    ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in options">
    <option value="">--Default--</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

just update model of the element i.e. `selectedOption='yourDefaultValue'`

What is the version of angular are you using?
if the latest one, then you can use below code::

```
    <select 
      ng-model="selectedOption" [ng-value]='yourDefaultValue'`
      ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in options">
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Link to updated plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/SkS0NqyXpnMcddu80anf?p=preview

Updating model code moved in the function and also `select as` and `track by` should be avoided as mentioned in the [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

`Be careful when using select as and track by in the same expression.`