# Angular JS: default value in select menu with ng-repeat options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have tried to follow the examples on the Angular 1.4.12 docs and what I've found here, still I cannot set a default value for a select menu.

My html (using `controller as` of `mob`):

```
<select name="userCurrencyType" 
   ng-model="mob.currencyType" 
   ng-options="s.name + ' - ' + s.code for s in mob.currencyTypes"></select>
```

Which correctly gives me a menu like:

[image]

Where my json is an array of objects:

```
[{ "code": "USD", "name": "United States Dollar" },
 { "code": "GBP", "name": "United Kingdom Pound" }...]
```

I want the default menu item to be the first item (USD).  I have tried setting the `ng-model` to `mob.currencyType` and setting this in the controller both like:

```
  _this.currencyType = _this.currencyTypes[0];
```

and

```
_this.currencyType = { "code": "USD", "name": "United States Dollar" }
```

Neither approach gives me a default value set.  What am I missing?

### UPDATE

After some good suggestions from other users, and some experimenting, it would seem the problem was my data service call was not returning a promise:

```
  _this.currencyTypes = MockDataFactory.query({ filename: 'currency_codes' });
```

So I added

```
 _this.currencyTypes.$promise.then(function () {
    init();
  });
```

And then

```
  function init () {
    _this.currencyType = _this.currencyTypes[0];
  }
```

Comment: There is a question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405483/how-do-i-set-the-default-option-for-select-with-angularjs/40408483) very similar.

Comment: I saw that.  As you can see, I tried that but it is not working.  `  _this.currencyType = _this.currencyTypes[0];`

Comment: works correctly here, after making some assumptions about the missing code bits: http://plnkr.co/edit/9FOxsbRUsUJgszcGMjKP?p=preview.  If this isn't what you expect, you should expand your code to clearly demonstrate this not working.

Comment: as a side note, I would highly advise against using `ng-init`, even though it seems to have worked in the supplied answer.  Firstly, the supplied answer changed your `ng-options` as well as used `ng-init`, and secondly, this is not what `ng-init` is intended for.

Comment: Is it because the data is being loaded from a factory? Perhaps something is not loaded when needed?

Comment: it's possible that something isn't matching up with the factory, but it's not really easy to just make guesses, which is why a [mcve] is very important.

Comment: I agree with @Claies, avoid the use of ng-init.

Comment: It was the data was not returned in a promise.  See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set using ng-init

```
<select ng-model="currency" ng-init="currency='United States Dollar'"   ng-options="code.name as code.name for code in currencyTypes">
</select>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/pzyJ5OmQVdNUklZbT1pX?p=preview)**

Comment: This worked as well: `ng-init="mob.currencyType = mob.currencyTypes[0]"`

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine, just include a track by:

```
<select name="userCurrencyType" 
ng-model="mob.currencyType" 
ng-options="s.name + ' - ' + s.code for s in mob.currencyTypes track by s.code"></select>
```