# Capturing checkbox values to table

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a form that will capture input, select and checkbox values and post them to a table. Everything seems to be working fine, with the exception of the checkboxes. What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/uvkzmyox/8/

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("ListController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.jobtypes = ['accountant', 'janitor', 'ceo', 'receptionist'];
    $scope.hobbies = [{name: "long walks on the beach", id: "1", isChecked: false},{name: "eating cheese", id: "2", isChecked: false},{name: "writing haikus", id: "3", isChecked: false},{name: "looking for bigfoot", id: "4", isChecked: false},{name: "watching police academy", id: "5", isChecked: false}];
$scope.personalDetails = [
    {
        'fname':'Muhammed',
        'lname':'Shanid',
        'jobtype': 'ceo',
        'email':'shanid@shanid.com',
        'active': true,
        'hobbies': [{name: "long walks on the beach", id: "1"},{name: "watching police academy", id: "5"}]
    },
    {
        'fname':'John',
        'lname':'Abraham',
        'jobtype': 'accountant',
        'email':'john@john.com',
        'active': true,
        'hobbies': [{name: "writing haikus", id: "3"},{name: "looking for bigfoot", id: "4"}]
    },
    {
        'fname':'Roy',
        'lname':'Mathew',
        'jobtype': 'janitor',
        'email':'roy@roy.com',
        'active': false,
        'hobbies': [{name: "eating cheese", id: "2"}]
    }];

    $scope.addNew = function(personalDetails){
        $scope.personalDetails.push({ 
            'fname': personalDetails.fname, 
            'lname': personalDetails.lname,
            'email': personalDetails.email,
            'jobtype': personalDetails.jobtype,
        });
        $scope.PD = {};
    };

    $scope.remove = function(){
        var newDataList=[];
        $scope.selectedAll = false;
        angular.forEach($scope.personalDetails, function(selected){
            if(!selected.selected){
                newDataList.push(selected);
            }
        }); 
        $scope.personalDetails = newDataList;
    };

    $scope.checkAll = function () {
        if (!$scope.selectedAll) {
            $scope.selectedAll = true;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
        }
        angular.forEach($scope.personalDetails, function (personalDetails) {
            personalDetails.selected = $scope.selectedAll;
        });
    }; 

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem your facing is caused by the fact that hobbies and their checked state is outside the scope of your `addNew(personalDetails)` function.

Although not ideal for angular, something like this would work:

```
$scope.addNew = function(personalDetails) {
    //get all checked hobbies
    let selectedHobbies = [];
    $scope.hobbies.forEach(function(hobby) {
        if (hobby.isChecked) selectedHobbies.push(hobby);
    });

        $scope.personalDetails.push({ 
            'fname': personalDetails.fname, 
            'lname': personalDetails.lname,
            'email': personalDetails.email,
            'jobtype': personalDetails.jobtype,
            'hobbies': selectedHobbies
        });
        $scope.PD = {};
    };
```

**EDIT**

The answer above is really a pure javascript approach to filtering by selected hobbies.  A more 'angular' approach would be to break your filter logic out into its own function so that you're not mixing concerns.  For example:

Add the 'filterFilter' dependency to your controller:

```
app.controller("ListController", ['$scope','filterFilter', 
    function($scope, filterFilter) { ... }
```

then in your controller, define an array to hold your selected hobbies and add a filter helper to filter by `isChecked`:

```
$scope.hobbiesSelection = [];
$scope.selectedHobbies = function selectedHobbies() {
    return filterFilter($scope.hobbies, { selected: true });
};
```

place a watch on the `hobbies` object to watch for changes to selected hobbies:

```
$scope.$watch('hobbies|filter:{isChecked: true}', function (hobbies) {
    $scope.hobbiesSelection = hobbies;
}, true);
```

and finally, you can update your `addNew()` method to simply be:

```
$scope.addNew = function(personalDetails){
    $scope.personalDetails.push({ 
        'fname': personalDetails.fname, 
        'lname': personalDetails.lname,
        'email': personalDetails.email,
        'jobtype': personalDetails.jobtype,
        'hobbies': $scope.selectedHobbies
    });
    $scope.PD = {};
};
```

So while there is a bit more code (and complexity) there for this example, you are separating the logic from the data a bit better.  There is working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/mt0tvkwm/

Comment: what do you mean by "not ideal for angular"? Is there a better way to do this outside of your suggestion? Just wondering as I'm new to angular and still learning. thanks axlj

Comment: @JosephSjoblom by not ideal, i meant that I wasn't using the angular toolbox to solve the problem.  please see my updated answer for details.

Comment: Hi @JosephSjoblom, did this help? Or Should I keep trying? :-)

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks axlj

Comment: axlj do you know how to set a default value to my select dropdown? I found an [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-angular-js-select-box), but didn't seem to work. I'm guessing it's because I've already populated my ng-model for the select?

Comment: your $scope.hobbies collection has a field: isChecked, you could set this to true when a value should be checked by default?

Comment: sorry, I was referring to the jobtypes array. The select menu is blank by default