# how to auto selected value angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

drop down are blank i want auto selected value Richard how do this, i am new in angular

```
  <select class="form-control" name="customer" id="customer" ng-model="postjobcustomerCtrl.selectedCustomer" ng-options="customer.full_name for customer in postjobcustomerCtrl.atlasCustomers  | filter:{full_name: Profile.full_name} track by customer.user_id"
ng-change="postjobcustomerCtrl.selectDefaultAddress()" required></select>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a default option in Angular.js select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-angular-js-select-box)

Comment: add `$cope.postjobcustomerCtrl = {selectedCustomer = 'value'}` in ngController.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use Angular's [ng-Init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to set a selected value inline.

```
<select class="form-control" name="customer" id="customer" ng-model="postjobcustomerCtrl.selectedCustomer" ng-options="customer.full_name for customer in postjobcustomerCtrl.atlasCustomers  | filter:{full_name: Profile.full_name} track by customer.user_id"
ng-change="postjobcustomerCtrl.selectDefaultAddress()" ng-init="postjobcustomerCtrl.selectedCustomer = 'Richard'" required></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `postjobcustomerCtrl`, initialize the select `ng-model` (`postjobcustomerCtrl.selectedCustomer`) with the `id` of *Richard*.

```
// angularjs controller

atlasCustomers = [{full_name : "Richard", user_id: 1}]        
postjobcustomerCtrl.selectedCustomer = atlasCustomers[0].atlasCustomers.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following...

```
<select ng-model="item">
  <option value="1">Bob</option>
  <option value="2">James</option>
  <option value="3">Karl</option>
</select>
```

... and you want James to be picked by default, then in the angular controller, you just do this:

```
$scope.item = 2;
```

Like so:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.item = 2;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="item">
    <option value="1">Bob</option>
    <option value="2">James</option>
    <option value="3">Karl</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to initialize your model with appropriate value("Richard") here to to get default value

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {
  $scope.postjobcustomerCtrl ={};
  $scope.postjobcustomerCtrl.atlasCustomers =[{"full_name":"Richard"},{"full_name":"Colins"},{"full_name":"Steve"}];
  
  $scope.postjobcustomerCtrl.selectedCustomer =$scope.postjobcustomerCtrl.atlasCustomers[0]
  $scope.postjobcustomerCtrl.selectDefaultAddress =function(){
    
  }
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  
   <select class="form-control" name="customer" id="customer" ng-model="postjobcustomerCtrl.selectedCustomer" ng-options="customer.full_name for customer in postjobcustomerCtrl.atlasCustomers"
ng-change="postjobcustomerCtrl.selectDefaultAddress()" required></select>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 myApp.Controller("MyCltr, function($scope){
     // first fetch data from db
     // bind data to drop-down
     // then set selected value.
     $scope.postjobcustomerCtrl.selectedCustomer = "Richard";

});
```

And please make sure once your drop-down is binded with data after that set this value.