# How to set default values to multi-select dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have a model (param) with properties:

- param.ValidValues (array of key-value pair)
- param.DefaultValues (array of value strings)

I am rendering **multi-select** dropdown

```
<select multiple ng-model="param.DefaultValues">
    <option ng-repeat="item in param.ValidValues" value="{{item.Value}}" label="{{item.Key}}" 
        ng-selected="???">
    </option>
</select>
```

Question:
How can I (using AngularJS markup syntax) **set default values** in this dropdown (**pre-select options that match whatever is in param.DefaultValues**) ?? Use ng-selected or there is another option?

For example:

if ValidValues = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
and DefaultValues = ["two", "three"]

then "two", "three" should be pre-selected. Makes sense?

Please note, I cant modify param.ValidValues collection.

Comment: On your controller you should save the value inside the select's `ngModel` - `$scope.param.DefaultValues = ['firstDefaultItemValue', 'secondDefaultItemValue'];`

Comment: @Alon Eitan, sorry, didnt get that. DefaultValues used to initialise the control, but also used as a model for user's selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as $ctrl">    
  <select multiple ng-model="$ctrl.selectedValues"
    ng-options="o.value as o.title for o in $ctrl.languages">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  <br>
  {{$ctrl.selectedValues}}
</div>
```

app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
this.languages = [
  {value: 'C#', title : 'C Sharp'},
  {value: 'PHP', title : 'p h p'},
  {value: 'Go', title : 'Go javascript'},
  {value: 'ES6', title: 'javascript'},
  {value: 'R', title: 'Rust'}
]   

this.selectedValues = ["C#","Go","R"];
});
```

Comment: I already have it: ng-model="param.DefaultValues"

Comment: Check this [link in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yurydg/pgt9tqg2/)

Answer (score 0):

try this
[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18195305/7475753)

```
<select multiple ng-model="param.DefaultValues" ng-init="param.DefaultValues = item[0]">
<option ng-repeat="item in param.ValidValues" value="{{item.Value}}"    label="{{item.Key}}" 
    ng-selected="???">
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But they ask about multiple options, not a single one

Comment: Sory, my mistake. I don't see this when i read.