# How to pre-select default options in <select "multiple"> element using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an object **param** that has these properties:

**param.ValidValues (key-value array)**

**param.DefaultValues (values string array)**

I need to bind ng-model="param.DefaultValues" and make all default values to be pre-selected in that select listbox, so that when a user makes multiple selection, the selected values are added to **param.DefaultValues array**

This code does the job well, please see the screenshot

```
<select multiple ng-model="param.DefaultValues">
    <option ng-repeat="item in param.ValidValues" value="{{item.Value}}" label="{{item.Key}}"></option>
</select>
```

[image]
However, the items, those values are in param.DefaultValues **are not pre-selected by default**.

**How can I achive that? Thanks**

If I use ng-options instead, it also does not pre-select DefaultValues, and also doesnt add user selected values to DefaulValues array:

```
<select ng-model="param.DefaultValues" ng-options="o.Value as o.Key for o in param.ValidValues" multiple>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look what values you are using to populate your default values

I use ng-options because it has a better performance

Check this example, I updated a few minutes ago. Please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882491/how-to-set-default-values-to-multi-select-dropdown/41883026#41883026)

I hope this will be useful for you.

Comment: Yury, I tried but it didnt work.  Have you seen the second option + the screenshot in this post? Isnt it the same as what you have? Could you do the Plunker and test if it works?