# How to show multiple values in an input element using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, arrays, input

I have an array of months like this

```
Array[0]
0
:
"January"
1
:
"February"
2
:
"March"
```

Now I need to show all three values of this array in one input element.
like 
[image]

How can I do this using angular js. Please help

here's the html

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <div asterick class="form-group" ng-class="{'form-group has-success': !error['months'] && (submitted), 'form-group has-error': (error['months']) && (submitted)}">
                    <label for="months">Months</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="year" ng-model="data.year" value="">
                    <input type="text" name="months" id="months" ng-model="data.months" class="form-control" ng-required="true">
                    <span class="er-block" ng-show="monthlyReportFormPage.months.$touched && monthlyReportFormPage.months.$error.required">Please select months.</span>
                    <span ng-show="error.months" class="er-block">{{error.months}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: show the html template

Comment: Make a try and then post your code and ask a question about that. Sorry but writing your code isn't our task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pre-select default options in <select "multiple"> element using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897635/how-to-pre-select-default-options-in-select-multiple-element-using-angularjs)

Comment: I have updated my question @sachila. sorry for late I was busy

Answer (score 1):

There're plenty of options:

- I would recommend to take a look at [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/).

  **HTML:**

  ```
  <input type="text" value="html,input,tag" data-role="tagsinput"></input>
  ```

  **CSS:**

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
  ```

  **JS:**

  ```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
  ```

  **RESULT:**

  [image]
- OR [jQuery Tags Input Plugin](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input) by XOXCO:

  [image]
- OR you can do it using *pure javascript*. Here's an [example](https://github.com/tovic/tags-input-beautifier).

Answer (score 0):

Hey in case you work with angular 1.X try the ui-select plugin (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki). I think its exactly what you are looking for. Here are some examples https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-multiple-selection.html.

best regards Peter