# How to specify default value in the select dropdown when ng-options has ng-repeat with the following structure of data?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-options

I have data in the following format:

```
tablecolumns{
{
    Tablecolumn_id:
    name:'First_column'
    DefaultValueForTheColumn:Object
        DefaultValue:"String"
        DefaultValueId:"some_numeric_value"
    TypeOfColumn:Object
        TypeofDataInColumn:"String"
        Value:Array[] /*No. of child elements i want to have in a string column drodown*/
                {
                id:1
                name:'nameofchildelement'
                value:'high'
                }
                {
                isSelectedAsDefault:'true'/*If the value is selected as default it holds true boolean*/
                id:2
                name:'nameofchildelement'
                value:'medium'
                }
                {
                id:1
                name:'nameofchildelement'
                value:'low'
                }

}
{
    Tablecolumn_id:
    name:'First_column'
    DefaultValueForTheColumn:Object
        DefaultValue:"String"
        DefaultValueId:"some_numeric_value"
    TypeOfColumn:Object
        TypeofDataInColumn:"String"
        Value:Array[] 
}
}
```

For the same i want to write a select dropdown that would by default have the string which has "true" condition in the data.

i have written the following:-

```
<select  ng-options="column.name for column in tablecolumns" ng-model="column.DefaultValueForTheColumn.DefaultValue" ></select>
```

But i am not getting any default value. Where am i goin' wrong?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-angular-js-select-box

Comment: The data is a bit different. Hence i am getting confused. Could you look into the same?

Comment: you just need to get the index of element which has true value for isSelectedAsDefault in your array and pass it to the ng-init

Comment: Let me try that, but are my ng-model and ng-options expressions fine?

Comment: No it should be an array... your tablecolumns is an object

Comment: so for this object how can i do it?

Comment: refer to the link above in first comment and format your data for ng-options in similar way as an array instead of object then you can follow the same example there.