# Select first value by default for a 'Select' box made dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I want to select the first option in a select box by default. The challenge here is that the page might have multiple select boxes as they are created dynamically.

You will understand what I am trying to achieve by looking at my code.

**HTML :**

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group form-group-grid" ng-repeat="fields in selectedTabData.requiredField" ng-switch="fields.paramType">
        <label>{{fields.paramName}}<span class="asterisk" ng-if="fields.mandatory==true">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-switch-when="Text" ng-model="fields.fieldValue" ng-attr-id="{{fields.paramName}}Id">
        <select class="form-control" ng-switch-when="DropDown" ng-options="field.paramKey as field.paramValue for field in fields.paramData" ng-model="fields.fieldValue" ng-attr-id="{{fields.paramName}}Id">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-inline-grid-button" ng-click="getReport()">Run Report</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The selected data is available under the model `$scope.selectedTabData.requiredField`

In Controller I push the selected values in to a variable like :

```
$scope.selectedTabData.requiredField.forEach(function(item) 
        {
                paramValue.push(item.fieldValue);
                paramName.push(item.paramName);
 })
```

I tried doing this :`ng-init="fields.fieldValue = fields.paramData[0]"`

```
<select class="form-control" ng-switch-when="DropDown" ng-options="field.paramKey as field.paramValue for field in fields.paramData" ng-model="fields.fieldValue" ng-init="fields.fieldValue = fields.paramData[0]" ng-attr-id="{{fields.paramName}}Id">
                                    </select>
```

I am not sure how it will work. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18195305/5751251

Comment: I think I already tried that. ng-init="fields.fieldValue = fields.paramData[0]"

Comment: This didnt work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make it possible by ng-repeat inside  tag

```
<select ng-model="fields.fieldValue">
     <option ng-repeat="field in fields.paramData" value="{{field.paramKey}}">
         {{field.value}}
     <option>
</select>
```

and in controller add this line

```
$scope.fields.fieldValue = x;
```

and in this example, x is "field.value" that you want as default selected option.

Comment: $scope.selectedTabData.requiredField.forEach(function(item) 
                    {
                            item.fieldValue = item.paramData[0].paramValue;
                    })

Comment: Is this how I should do it? The above code is not working for me

Comment: Never mind, I still had Ng-init in my html, thats why it was not working. I removed it and then, voilà... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the plunkr for your problem
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/mahONdv5xQBa5eUZJSoX