# Default selected value in drop down not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-select

I have a drop down which by default on page load it select "PLEASE SELECT USECASE" in the dropdown

[image]

But i am expecting "EUC Proxy" to be selected on page load instead of "PLEASE SELECT USECASE"

[image]

***HTML IS SHOWN BELOW***

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="bot">Use Case</label>
                            <select id="select" formControlName="useCase" class="form-control" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="scheduleModel.UsecaseId">
                                <option value="-1" [selected]="isSelected"> Please Select Use Case </option>
                                <option *ngFor="let uc of useCaseList"  [value]="uc.BOTId"> {{uc.BOTName}}
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

***HTML i CHANGED TO ***

> [selected]="1"

But it doesn't made any difference.See the changed HTML Below

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="bot">Use Case</label>
                                <select id="select" formControlName="useCase" class="form-control" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="scheduleModel.UsecaseId">
                                                                            <option *ngFor="let uc of useCaseList" [selected]="1" [value]="uc.BOTId"> {{uc.BOTName}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

***SAME IN IMAGE***
[image]

I am getting "test Bot" selected in drop-down, which is last item in the drop down like below:

[image]

But i am expecting this: where uc.BOTId =1 is "EUC Proxy"  Not "test Bot"

[image]

***TS file***

```
 ngOnInit() {
  getUsecaseList() {
      this.manageBotService.getAllBots().subscribe(res => this.useCaseList = res);

  }
}
```

Why i am unable to select "EUC Proxy" which having uc.BOTId =1 on page load?

Comment: Can you add the function where you initialize your formGroup?

Comment: i didnt unsterstood ? which function ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a default option in Angular.js select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194255/how-to-have-a-default-option-in-angular-js-select-box)

Comment: this is angularjs and i am in angular 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove [selected] from your options.

The [(ngModel)] part from your 'select' will set the value to selected (depending on the value the 'scheduleModel.UsecaseId' has.

Comment: thank you  this.scheduleModel.UsecaseId = 1;  worked , since you given the first hint i am acepting this

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see you using the instruction that makes it default:

```
value='default'
```

for instance:

```
<select name='test'>
<option value='default' selected='selected'>Please select the value</option>
<option value='value1'>value1</option>
<option value='value2'>value2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i did this , but not worked  <option *ngFor="let uc of useCaseList" selected='1' [value]="uc.BOTId"> {{uc.BOTName}}
                                        </option>

Comment: But as I said, I don't see the value='default' statement on your html. value='default' must be exactly written like this

Comment: Try 
<option value='default' *ngFor="let uc of useCaseList" selected='1' [value]="uc.BOTId"> {{uc.BOTName}} </option>

Answer (score 1):

Set `scheduleModel.UsecaseId = 1` after loading the drop-down on `ng-init()`.

Comment: thank you it works , since your answer comes second, i am accepting the other answer... thanks a lot

Comment: No Prob :) glad to help :)