# How to add default option in select for AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know why this is not adding a default selected view:

I thought ng-init would make it have a default selected view.

How do I make the drop down box menu have a default selected value?

```
<select ng-init="selectedCar = Cars[0]" ng-model="selectedCar" class="form-control" ng-required="true">
    <option value="" selected>Select a job title</option>
    <option ng-repeat="car in Cars" ng-value="car.firstname car.lastname">
        {{car.firstname}} {{car.lastname}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: can u add your TS code?

Comment: ng-model should initialized with value of option. just rewrite it as,
<select ng-init="selectedCar = Cars[0].firstname+' '+Cars[0].firstname"
      <option value="" selected>Select a job title</option>
       <option ng-repeat="car in Cars" ng-value="car.firstname car.lastname">
                                                                        {{car.firstname}} {{car.lastname}}
 </select>

Answer (score 1):

You can try to initialize `selectedCar` in your controller rather `ng-init`.

Try the below code.

In your controller initialize it.
For e.g:
$scope.selectedCar = $scope.Cars[0];

And in the template:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCar" class="form-control" ng-required="true">
    <option value="" selected>Select a job title</option>
    <option ng-repeat="car in Cars" ng-value="car.firstname car.lastname" ng-selected="selectedCar.id == car.id">
        {{car.firstname}} {{car.lastname}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Or

You can try using `ng-options`. Reference [Another way by using ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34885609/5349053)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value for the select element by binding the ng-model with the variable you assigned with ng-init since ng-init doesn't assign the default value for the select and option components, but the default value to a variable in the scope.
Try using selected in option to select the default value.

```
<select ng-init="selectedCar = Cars[0]" ng-model="selectedCar" class="form-control" ng-required="true">
<option value="" selected>Select a job title</option>
<option ng-repeat="car in Cars" ng-value="car.firstname car.lastname" selected>
    {{car.firstname}} {{car.lastname}}
</option>
```

Or you can use ng-selected

```
<select ng-init="selectedCar = Cars[0]" ng-model="selectedCar" class="form-control" ng-required="true">
<option value="" selected>Select a job title</option>
<option ng-repeat="car in Cars" ng-value="car.firstname car.lastname" ng-selected="$first">
    {{car.firstname}} {{car.lastname}}
</option>
```